# IBM MobileFirst setting heartbeat logs error in console

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

When I try to set heartbeat value for WLClient before connecting it, following error is logged in console.

```
[ERROR] [WL_CLIENT] -[WLClient setHeartBeatInterval:] in WLClient.m:245 :: WLClient has not been initialized
```

I do the setting using following code.

```
[self.wLClient setHeartBeatInterval:newValue];
```

Behaviour is different on Android. On Android if heartbeat value is set before connecting no error is logged, moreover, setting seems to take effect.

Following are two main question.

1. Is this a bug or iOS SDK intentionally block this type of setting before connect?
2. Is there any other possible way to configure WLClient heartbeat before connect?

I am using MobileFirst Platform 7.1

Answer (score 0):

You would not need connection to server before setting heartbeat interval, however you will need to initialise the WLClient before using the `setHeartBeatInterval` API. (`[WLClient sharedInstance]` should be called before using this API.)

Try this:
`[[WLClient sharedInstance]setHeartBeatInterval:newValue];`

Comment: I am `[WLClient sharedInstance]` before calling `setHeartBeatInterval:newValue `. Still it shows the error log.